# Python android app for raspberry pi using ssh

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, ssh, raspberry-pi4

this is probably a pretty easy question, but I don't really know what to search, so far I couldn't get the answers I need.

I have a program that tracks a web page. As I don't need it everyday but only on specific days and also the sub pages I track differ from day to day, I wrote a small GUI that has different selections on which page to track as well as a button to start the the program on the Rasperry Pi.
Getting to my question:

How do I get this "start button" to work, meaning how do I implement ssh in my program for one button, but a normal input for the second button. I need to get it to work on android (I wrote the GUI with kivy, so this shouldn't be a problem). I don't really know where to start looking so maybe you can give me any direction serves my duty and if it is possible or I should use one of the available apps like rasperry ssh or mercury ssh.

Greetings
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

you cand do something like this:-

```
subprocess.Popen("ssh {user}@{host} {cmd}".format(user=user, host=host, cmd='ls -l'), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, seems like I need to google a bit around it, but  hopefully it's gonna work.